# WCF NetHttpBinding in MonoTouch

Tags: wcf, xamarin

Does/Will MonoTouch support the new **NetHttpBinding** of WCF 4.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetHttpBinding is a binding designed for consuming HTTP or WebSocket services. But it only uses WebSocket on Windows 8, otherwise it uses Http.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nethttpbinding.aspx

Mono touch supports the same client bindings as silverlight 3 which means basichttpbinding. (atleast according to the latest info I have been able to find)

In your case since you are using xamarin, I assume that you are not running on Windows 8, therefore you are probably stuck with basichttpbinding.